# Detect duplicate code in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, code-duplication

Clone Detective was a great tool for finding duplicate code in VS 2008.

Are there any tools for finding duplicate code which integrate into VS 2010?

*Clone Detective doesn't look like its being actively developed [1](http://clonedetectivevs.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=206611) [2](http://clonedetectivevs.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets).

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204177/what-tool-to-find-code-duplicates-in-c-projects

Comment: @IanRingrose link is broken

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(You don't seem to have gotten any answers after a couple of weeks... hints there aren't any that do exactly what you want).

Our [CloneDR](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/Clone) is a tool that detects cloned code for C# 4.0 and modern Microsoft C++ dialects, parsing to abstract syntax trees to drive the clone detection process.  This produces, IMHO, a higher-quality result than the token-based scheme used by ConQAT (which Clone Detective uses).  You can see sample reports at the provided link.

CloneDR doesn't specifically integrate into VS 2010, but it does run under Windows and its command-line variant could be easily attached as a VS 2010 custom action.   It is under continual enhancement.

EDIT October 2010:   CloneDR now supports VB.net, through version 10.0.

EDIT November 2015:  Now supports VS2013 C++ and C# 5.0 (C# 6.0 coming!)

Comment: Hey Ira, thanks for the suggestion.  I'm just using the evaluation version now and it is a very nice tool.